# Cant't find out where replace the nonce to get a blob hash

Tags: mining, mining-pools, mining-theory, cryptonight, proof-of-work

I'm trying to understand the basics of mining and have a very specific question about hashing a blob. When I start a miner and capture the packets, I get a job from the pool and then the work submitted by the miner.

Job recieved from the pool:

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "job": {
      "blob": "0b0befdeecee051358860383d8e14f3529859e0c2f64c31a631addef3f9ca97eedcc738324fbd9000000009e18d5ad6a814f39bb79c9558f292aea7101e154c114e57c2205732d2e8b7eca02",
      "target": "37894100",
      "job_id": "8241143554386990819",
      "time_to_live": 5,
      "height": 1974336,
      "algo": "cn/r"
    },
    "status": "OK",
    "id": "1177745781301023725"
  },
  "id": 1,
  "error": null
}
```

I think that I have classified these right, if not please correct me:

- Versions: **0b0b**
- Timestamp: **efdeecee05**
- Prev Id:
  **1358860383d8e14f3529859e0c2f64c31a631addef3f9ca97eedcc738324fbd9**
- Nonce: **00000000**
- Transactions Tree Root:
  **9e18d5ad6a814f39bb79c9558f292aea7101e154c114e57c2205732d2e8b7eca**
- Transaction Count: **02**
- Hashing blob: **0b0befdeecee051358860383d8e14f3529859e0c2f64c31a631addef3f9ca97eedcc738324fbd9000000009e18d5ad6a814f39bb79c9558f292aea7101e154c114e57c2205732d2e8b7eca02**

Share that the pool accepted:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "submit",
  "params": {
    "id": "1177745781301023725",
    "job_id": "8241143554386990819",
    "nonce": "41000000",
    "result": "78aeeba968470a2b000c42e46ce60e3e422efbd2fb58fa275384855cd8131d00"
  }
}
```

My question boils down to:
Where in the blob **0b0befdeecee051358860383d8e14f3529859e0c2f64c31a631addef3f9ca97eedcc738324fbd9000000009e18d5ad6a814f39bb79c9558f292aea7101e154c114e57c2205732d2e8b7eca02** do I need to insert the nonce **41000000** to get the result **78aeeba968470a2b000c42e46ce60e3e422efbd2fb58fa275384855cd8131d00** after feeding the blob through the CryptoNight hashing algorithm?

If my understanding is correct, I need to replace the bytes 00000000 with the 41000000 found nonce, but when I do that, the resulting hash is different from the miner submitted hash.

I'm using a C implementation of CryptoNight and I'm checking the results with an online implementation that I found [here](https://xmr.llcoins.net/slowhash.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the correct location for the nonce bytes. However, are you using the same CryptoNight *variant*? I doubt this.

The current version (CN/R), also requires a *height* parameter as input. Therefore we can know for sure the version [you linked to](https://xmr.llcoins.net/slowhash.html) is not using CN/R (it is not asking for a height parameter as input). So *unless* you are mining to an old pool / chain, you can also be pretty certain you are mining CN/R, which explains why your result hash sent to the pool differs from the one using the link.

Comment: No problem. Easy to overlook.